# Llamar desde JS a una función en views.py. Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

Estoy empleando Django para un proyecto y desde hace días quiero implementar un botón que me ejecute una función `python` que se encuentra en `views.py`, pero no consigo entender cómo se realiza. Veo que muchas de las respuestas inglesas lo solucionan empleando `ajax` pero sigo sin ver cómo se hace.

En `views.py` tengo una sencilla función

```
def funcionPruebas(b):
    a = 1+b
    return a
```

En mi `index.html` tengo un simple botón que sería el que ejecute la función..

```
<input type="button" value="Filtrar" class="boton" onclick="funcion();">
```

Por último tengo mi `fichero.js` que sería el encargado de llamar a `funcionPruebas()` situada en `view.py`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '../../views.py',
        data: {'Valor': 5},
        success: funcionPrueba (Valor) {
             //this gets called when server returns an OK response
             alert("it worked!");
             alert(RESULTADO DE LA FUNCION)
        },
        error: funcionPrueba (Valor) {
             alert("it didnt work");
        }
    });
});
```

Tengo esa `url` porque al mismo nivel que `views.py` hay una carpeta llamada `static` y a su vez otra llamada `js` que es la contenedora del fichero.

Siento no dar más información pero es que no ser por donde tirar. Ni siquiera tengo claro que sea por aquí el camino correcto a mi problema.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

> Lo siento por mi castellano, estoy aprendido

Me parece que estas probando aplicar conceptos de PHP con Django. Sin embargo, no funciona de esta manera: Django hará analizar cada solicitud HTTP que haces y enrutarála a la vista correcta. No hay ningun correlación entre la URL de solicitud y la vista.

Mejor, tienes que describir la correspondencia entre las URLs y las funciónes en `urls.py`. Te sugiero que lees el [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.2/intro/tutorial01/) para tener ideas mas claras y particularmente la parte "[Escriba su primera vista](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.2/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view)".

En su caso, necesitarías de hacer la vista siguiente en su archivo `views.py`:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core.exceptions import SuspiciousOperation

def funcionPruebas(request):
    try:
        b = int(request.POST['Valor'])
    except (ValueError, KeyError):
        raise SuspiciousOperation('Invalid POST parameters')

    a = 1 + b

    return JsonResponse({'result': a})
```

Este código buscará los valores que pase dentro de `request.POST`. El `try`/`except` código aquí solo es por validar que el valor está presente y que se puede ser convertir en un `int`. Se podría hacer con [Django Forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms).

La función devuelve una `JsonResponse`, que serializará su respuesta en JSON y establecerá los headers HTTP correctamente. De esta manera, su jQuery código puede entender la respuesta.

Y entonces desde el `urls.py` de su app necesite de escribir un a cosa como

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    # Otras vistas aqui
    # ...
    path('function-pruebas', views.functionPruebas, name='index'),
]
```

> **Nota** — Esto espera que hayas seguido la estructura del tutorial

Esto creará una nueba URL como `/mi-app/function-pruebas`. No puedo saber qué URL es exactamente porque no publicó sus archivos `urls.py`. Tienes que adivinar las URL tú mismo o publicar los archivos aquí.

Luego, desde el lado JS, simplamente puede llamar a la función de esta manera:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/mi-app/function-pruebas',
        data: {'Valor': 5},
        success: funcionPrueba (data) {
             //this gets called when server returns an OK response
             console.log('it worked!');
             console.log(data.result);
        },
        error: funcionPrueba () {
             console.log("it didnt work");
        }
    });
});
```

Como la `JsonResponse` envía `{'result': a}` entonces este es la valor que encontramos en `data`.  Asi el valor que está buscando está en `data.result`.

Comment: A mi esta solución no me funciono